# How to create Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Unlimited<T> structure with Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, exchange-server

I'm developing a powershell script to modify some Microsoft Exchange mailboxes. I want to add a parameter to my function with data type "ByteQuantifiedSize" as it is used for mailbox quotas.

A simple example:

```
function generateSubscriptionInformation
{
param(            
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]$StandardQuota         
)
write-host $StandardQuota
}
generateSubscriptionInformation -StandardQuota 12345 #works
generateSubscriptionInformation -StandardQuota unlimited #doesn't work
```

How can I set a unlimited value via parameter? Look also at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/exchange-server/exchange-150/ff340799%28v%3dexchg.150%29 .

I cannot create a unlimited value or variable like

1.
`` new-object "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Unlimited`1[[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize, Microsoft.Exchange
.Data,Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]" ``

2. `New-Object 'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Unlimited[ByteQuantifiedSize]'`

Who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bsh
$typeParam    = [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]
$concreteType = [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Unlimited`1].MakeGenericType(@($typeParam))
$unlimitedBQS = [System.Activator]::CreateInstance($concreteType)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I could successfully create a variable as you suggested. Unfortunately, the default value seems to be unlimited=$false. How can I set the variable to unlimited? The property isUnlimited does not allow to modify the value.

Comment: @PSaR You'll probably have to declare the parameter to be of type `[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Unlimited[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]]` as well

Comment: Thank you, Mathias R. Jessen. This was the solution.